# Qualitative Ordinary Differential Equations Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find some continuously differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ and some number a such that the unique solution to the initial value problem 
$\dot{x}(t)=f(x(t))$, $x(0)=a$
is undefined at $t=.001$. (It should be possible to do this problem with $f(x)=x^2$, though you can choose any $f$ that works for you.)

Ok, so I am a little confused about what this question is asking. I just starting a class called Qualitative Ordinary Differential Equations and he never went over a problem like this. 
I feel like I should integrate both sides, but there really isn't much of a problem here. If we want $x(t)$ to be undefined at $t=.001$, can we just make $x(t)= 1.001t-1$ and $a=-1$?

Answer (score 0):

You don't get to choose x(t).  You choose f, and x(t) is the solution to the ODE.  Try solving $\dot{x}=x^2$ as is suggested.  You will get a function that is undefined for some value of t, depending on your chosen initial condition.  Then figure out which initial condition puts that undefined value at t=.001.

Comment: So I can make my initial condition anything? I still do not really understand what you are saying. So I need to make an initial condition that makes it undefined at t=.001. So wouldn't x(dot)=x^2+.001 and then when x=0 x(dot)=.001?

Comment: So ∫x^2=dt. (1/3)x^3=t+c. x^3=3t+C. x=(3t)^(1/3)+C. Am I doing this right at all?

Comment: So C=.001? I really have no idea what I am doing if this is not right. Can someone please just show me what to do for this one so I can get future problems like this?

Comment: Have you heard of separation of variables (technique for solving ODEs)?